# ¿Como validar un campo dependiendo de otro valor con REACT YUP?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validación

tengo un formulario en react y utilizo el esquema de validación de YUP.
Tengo un objeto estado:{nombre: ""}
Dependiendo del valor de este estado, otros campos deberian ser obligatorios.
Encontre la funcion .when. En el siguiente ejemplo, si el estado es diferente a "FF" y "GG" el campo debe ser obligatorio.

```
export const formValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  estado: Yup.object({
    nombre: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  }),

  edad: Yup.number()
    .when("estado.nombre", {
      is: (value) => value !== "FF" && value !== "GG",
      then: Yup.number().required("Required"),
      otherwise: Yup.number(),
    })
});
```

El ejemplo funciona perfectamente, si en el campo estado se ingresa FF o GG, edad deja de ser obligatorio.
Pero cuando uso esa misma logica en un objeto o array. deja de funcionar

```
export const formValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  estado: Yup.object({
    nombre: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  }),

  edad: Yup.number()
    .when("estado.nombre", {
      is: (value) => value !== "FF" && value !== "GG",
      then: Yup.number().required("Required"),
      otherwise: Yup.number(),
    })

  departamento: Yup.object({
    nombre: Yup.string().when("estado.nombre", {
      is: (value) => value !== "FF" && value !== "GG",
      then: Yup.string().required("Required"),
      otherwise: Yup.string(),
  }),
});
```

Seguramente no funcione el value, dentro de otros objetos o array, como podria solucionarlo ?